# Neo4j Cypher query need help getting expected response

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello – I am looking for help with a cypher query that is not returning expected results for the question “Which boards is node1 pinned to depending on which user is logged in?”

Wrong result is obtained for user2. I expected that the OPTIONAL MATCH would "catch" user2 being a member of the workgroup that can access the board.

I've tried several different combinations of MATCH statements, UNION, etc.

Thanks - Jeff

I created a graph in http://console.neo4j.org/ with the following query:

```
CREATE (N1:node { name:"node1" })-[:PINNED_TO]->(B1:board { name:"board1" }),(N1)-[:PINNED_TO]->(B2:board { name:"board2" }),(N1)-[:PINNED_TO]->(B3:board { name:"board3" })
CREATE (U1:user { name:"user1" })-[:CREATES]->(B1),(U1)-[:CREATES]->(B2),(U3:user { name:"user3" })-[:CREATES]->(B3)
CREATE (B1)-[:CAN_VIEW]->(V1:view { name:"creator" }),(B2)-[:CAN_VIEW]->(V2:view { name:"creator AND workgroup" }),(B3)-[:CAN_VIEW]->(V3:view { name:"everyone" })
CREATE (U2:user { name:"user2" })-[:MEMBER_OF]->(WG2:workgroup { name:"B2 workgroup" })-[:CAN_ACCESS]->(B2)
```

I then queried the graph with the following (substituting user.name for each user):

```
MATCH (n:node)-[p:PINNED_TO]->(b:board)
MATCH (v:view)<-[:CAN_VIEW]-(b)<-[:CREATES]-(logged_in_user: user)
WHERE v.name = 'everyone' OR logged_in_user.name='user2'
OPTIONAL MATCH (b)<-[can_access:CAN_ACCESS]-(wg:workgroup)<-[:MEMBER_OF]-(logged_in_user)
WHERE logged_in_user.name='user2' OR can_access IS NOT NULL
RETURN DISTINCT logged_in_user.name, n.name, type(p), b.name
```

If “user1” is logged in, I correctly get the following:

```
logged_in_user.name n.name  type(p)     b.name
user1               node1   PINNED_TO   board1
user1               node1   PINNED_TO   board2
user1               node1   PINNED_TO   board3
```

If “user2” is logged in, I **incorrectly** get the following:

```
logged_in_user.name n.name  type(p)     b.name
user2               node1   PINNED_TO   board3
```

It should have returned:

```
logged_in_user.name n.name  type(p)     b.name
user2               node1   PINNED_TO   board2
user2               node1   PINNED_TO   board3
```

If “ user3” is logged in, I correctly get the following:

```
logged_in_user.name n.name  type(p)     b.name
user3               node1   PINNED_TO   board3
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but you have two different cases for the `workgroup` node label: `workgroup` in the CREATE statement and `workGroup` in the MATCH, which will not match since labels are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. However, as @cybersam mentioned, that was not enough to fix the issue because      user2 does not have an outgoing relationship to     board2. I expected that the OPTIONAL MATCH would "catch" that but it is failing, I'll try more specification of nodes in that portion of the query. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`U1` and `U3` have an outgoing `CREATES` relationship, but `U2` (for `user2`) does not -- so your second `MATCH` will never match `U2`.

Also, as @WilliamLyon said, you need to use `workgroup` instead of `workGroup` in your query. But fixing that would not be sufficient to make your query work.

Comment: Got it. I understand why it is failing. I'll try more specification of nodes in that portion of the query. Any ideas on how to "catch" board2?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using     UNION MATCH instead of     OPTIONAL MATCH. For more nformation see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-union.html

Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions. Cheers.